# How to add custom image on native map in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

currently i am working on native map in Titanium for android and iOS.

you might have seen native maps on which a custom image layer or layout is being displayed, which will rotate and zoom according to the user input (currently i am not talking about annotations)

i have tried using annotation map tile too but it doesn't seems to work as the native map app i have seen

if you have any question or are not able to understand my question please let me know so i could clarify and get solution for one of you

Update:
Can you give a better explanation of what you've tried?

you might already know about mapbox.com and leafletjs.com, by using their library we could make customize maps and offline map in webview but i am looking for some Titanium module which could help me use native map of iOS and android for performing similar functionalities(i am avoiding commercial library and plugins as my app is not commercial app). i want to create map tiles which could be used for offline purpose as the user would have downloaded with the app.

what i have tried yet!!

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLiNh.jpg

2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOLO7.jpg

in first image link i have given image in which i showing screenshot of map with rotation (if you notice compass) and the map tile moved accordingly to it
in 2nd image ... i had put a map tile using createAnnontation function, but unable to fix its layout remains same and it doesn't resize when i do zoom in/out too

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of what you've tried?

Comment: and also a sample of "native maps on which a custom image layer or layout is being displayed" perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about custom tiles on top of a MapView.

There is an example module for iOS at https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Map which used the Titanium map module as a base. It is a bit dated, but see the TileOverlay example and code and it will get you on the right track.

The best tutorial I've found on how to create the tiles is at http://www.ericbinnion.com/creating-custom-overlays-for-ios-mapkit-framework/

I've tried to create a similar TileOverlay functionality by forking the Android map module with limited success.  I never got it to work as well as the native maps.

You could also check out using [Mapbox with Titanium](https://github.com/adampax/titanium-mapbox).  There are great tutorials and tools for creating your own tiles layers and manipulating existing layers.  [Adam Paxton gave a great demo of it at TiConf in New York](http://vimeo.com/96898505) this year.